# SQL: Group by datetime field but only use the date with the date used elsewhere in the query

Tags: sql

I am struggling to get this query right.

```
SELECT CallCategory, COUNT(CallCategory) as Total

,SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW, ResolvedDate), 1, 3) As 'Day'
,SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW, ResolvedDate), 1, 3) As 'Day'
,DATEPART(WEEK, ResolvedDate) As 'Week'
,CONVERT(CHAR(3), ResolvedDate, 0) As 'Month'
,DATEPART(YEAR, ResolvedDate) As 'Year'

,DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) As CurrentWeek
,CONVERT(CHAR(3), GETDATE(), 0) As CurrentMonth
,DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) As CurrentYear


,Case When DATEPART(WEEK, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End As IsThisWeek

,Case When DATEPART(WEEK, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) -1 Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End As IsLastWeek

,Case When CONVERT(CHAR(3), ResolvedDate, 0) = CONVERT(CHAR(3), GETDATE()) Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End As IsThisMonth

,Case When DATEPART(YEAR, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End As IsThisYear

,Case When DATEPART(yy, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) and DATEPART(mm, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) and DATEPART(dd, ResolvedDate) = DATEPART(dd, GETDATE())
Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End As IsToday

,case when DATEPART(WEEK, convert(date,ResolvedDate, 105)) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) -4 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as MonthOld

FROM prcDepartmentHelpDesks WHERE SupportTeam = 'Some Team' AND ResolvedDate >=   '2016-02-09'

GROUP BY  CAST(ResolvedDate AS DATE) , CallCategory
```

it keeps asking me to add ResolvedDate in an aggregrate or into the group by. If I comment out the case whens and the date parts then it works.

Comment: Move almost all of it into a derived table. Keep the GROUP BY at main level.

Comment: From jarlh's suggestion: add a column in your query, cast(ResolvedDate as DATE) as ResolvedDateCast. Get rid of the group by bit, nest the whole query, and put group by ResolvedDateCast, CallCategory at the main level.

Comment: You cast `ResolvedDate` to DATE. So what datatype is `ResolvedDate` originally? Do you use this CAST to strip the time part from a datetime column? And what is your DBMS?

Comment: Seeing this awkward date handling, this must be SQL Server, right? In another DBMS you would simply do something like `to_char(resolveddate,'yyyymm') = to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')` in order to compare a month. Apropos: be aware that a week number alone doesn't tell you whether two dates are in the same week; you must compare the year, too.

Comment: Which DBMS are you  using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You group by `CAST(ResolvedDate AS DATE)` - supposedly because in spite of its name ResolvedDate is not a date but a datetime and you want to get rid of the time part.

Thus you group by date and when there are two records for one call category on the same date, you want to get one result record for them and count 2. But then, in your SELECT clause you are referring to `ResolvedDate`, e.g. here: `DATEPART(WEEK, ResolvedDate) As 'Week'`. But *what* `ResolvedDate`? There are two different datetimes for the group. That means you can no longer access `ResolvedDate` in the SELECT clause, but only `CAST(ResolvedDate AS DATE)`.

So you can solve your problem by replacing all `ResolvedDate` by `CAST(ResolvedDate AS DATE)` in your SELECT clause. It can be more convenient though, to cast just once and work on this result (i.e. using a derived table, a subquery in the FROM clause). Your query would then look like below:

```
select
   callcategory
  ,total
  ,substring(datename(weekday, resolveddate), 1, 3) as day
  ,datepart(week, resolveddate) as week
  ,substring(datename(month, resolveddate), 1, 3) as month
  ,datepart(year, resolveddate) as year
  ,datepart(week, today) as currentweek
  ,substring(datename(month, today), 1, 3) as currentmonth
  ,datepart(year, today) as currentyear
  ,case when datename(year, resolveddate) + datename(week, resolveddate) = datename(year, today) + datename(week, today) then 'yes' else 'no' end as isthisweek
  ,case when datename(year, resolveddate) + datename(week, resolveddate) = datename(year, oneweekago) + datename(week, oneweekago) then 'yes' else 'no' end as islastweek
  ,case when datename(year, resolveddate) + datename(month, resolveddate) = datename(year, today) + datename(month, today) then 'yes' else 'no' end as isthismonth
  ,case when datename(year, resolveddate) = datename(year, today) then 'yes' else 'no' end as isthisyear
  ,case when resolveddate = today then 'yes' else 'no' end as istoday
  ,case when datename(year, resolveddate) + datename(week, resolveddate) = datename(year, fourweeksago) + datename(week, fourweeksago) then 'yes' else 'no' end as monthold
from
(
  select 
    callcategory,
    cast(resolveddate as date) as resolveddate,
    cast(getdate() as date) as today,
    cast(dateadd(week, -1, getdate()) as date) as oneweekago,
    cast(dateadd(week, -4, getdate()) as date) as fourweeksago,
    count(*) as total
  from prcdepartmenthelpdesks 
  where supportteam = 'some team'
  and resolveddate >= '2016-02-09'
  group by callcategory, cast(resolveddate as date)
) grouped;
```

I've corrected some evaluations, e.g. taking the year into consideration for IsThisWeek. There may still be errors, I forgot to remove or that I even introduced. Look at the formulas closely and decide if they do for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to a derived table. While I did not use your exact example the thinking got me on the right track and the problem has gone away :)